# How to represent multiple values in a single bar graph against single axis in matlab?

Tags: matlab, graph, bar-chart

i want to represent `9` values in a single Bar Graph, separately representing them is easy but i want to represent them in a single graph accurately.
Observations are:

```
x=[0.22,0.34,0.42]
bar(x,0.1,'stacked')
somenames={'IND Relation' ; 'DIS Relation' ; 'EQ Relation'}
set(gca,'xticklabel',somenames)
ylabel('F1')

x=[0.25,0.43,0.53]
bar(x,0.1,'stacked')
somenames={'IND Relation' ; 'DIS Relation' ; 'EQ Relation'}
set(gca,'xticklabel',somenames)
ylabel('F1')

x=[0.22,0.43,0.56]
bar(x,0.1,'stacked')
somenames={'IND Relation' ; 'DIS Relation' ; 'EQ Relation'}
set(gca,'xticklabel',somenames)
ylabel('F1')
```

Sample output of 1st chunk(5 lines) is is:
[image]

Similarly i have separate graph's for other two observations aswell, I want to represent all three graphs together in a single Bar graph in same order i.e a single bar graph containing total `9` Bars first three bars should represent 1st three values with `IND` `DIS` and `EQ` bars and similarly next group of values till each `9` values of `x` are represented.

i've tried following but didn't obtained desired resuls:

```
x = [0.22,0.34,0.42; 0.25,0.43,0.53; 0.22,0.43,0.56];
bar(x,0.1,'stacked')
somenames={'IND Relation' ; 'DIS Relation' ; 'EQ Relation'}
set(gca,'xticklabel',somenames)
ylabel('F1')
```

Comment: try `bar(x,0.8,'grouped')`

Comment: Do you just want a clustered bar chart (which is the default)? e.g. something that looks like this `y = [2 2 3; 2 5 6; 2 8 9; 2 11 12]; bar(y)`

Comment: @Dan yes i want clustered bar chat it helped me representing values secondly i want to label them as well instead of `1,2,3` on x axis i want to write `Lexical chains`,`Microsoft` and `Auto summarize`

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior i wanted `9` different bar charts as @dan mentioned

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad `set(gca,'xticklabel',somenames)` is still the correct way to fix that. Just arrange your data the way the docs are `y` (i.e. like in my previous column). Although `somenames` is never a good variable name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
x=[0.22,0.25,0.22;
   0.34,0.43,0.43;
   0.42,0.53,0.56]

bar(x);
group_labels={'IND Relation' ; 'DIS Relation' ; 'EQ Relation'}
set(gca,'xticklabel',group_labels);
ylabel('F1');
```